# Substitute jquery .is(:hover) pseudo element

Tags: jquery, timeout

I use the following code-snippet on my page …

```
if ( $("#footer, #header").is(':visible') && && !$("#footer, #header").is(':hover') ) {
```

I upgraded to the latest jQuery Version and now this `.is(:hover)` is no longer supported.

How do I subistute this in my code above. I googled already and found a few threads regarding this issue, but couldn't seem to find an appropriate solution for my code above.

I use this code to handle a `timeout` event. If my mouse is over the header or footer, I don't want the timeout to be cleared.

Comment: Can you not just select with `#footer:hover`?

Comment: On which jq version this was working: `$("#footer, #header").is(':visible') && && !$("#footer, #header").is(':hover')` ???

Comment: Regarding `.is(':hover')` it works in latest jq version, both 1.x and 2.x branch **BUT** of course, this doesn't work `&& &&`, so use: `$("#footer, #header").is(':visible') && !$("#footer, #header").is(':hover')`

Comment: @A.Wolff http://f.cl.ly/items/1c1Y3G2F1c2h0d3z3C2j/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-13%20at%2016.02.49.png `if ( $("#footer, #header").is(':visible') && !$("#footer, #header").is(':hover') && !fmVideo.paused ) {` this is my code. I use jQuery 1.11.1.min.js

Comment: @matt Interresting, looks like using ***OR*** CSS selector throws error `$("#footer, #header")` using it with `is(':hover')`

Comment: @A.Wolff any solution or idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class on the hover event for the elements and then check the class exists.

Toggle class on hover:

```
$("#footer, #header").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Check for class:

```
if (!$("#footer, #header").hasClass('hover')) { 
     //do  your stuff
});
```